# Unable to open jupyterlab on Google compute notebook instance

Tags: google-compute-engine

I am unable to access Jupyterlab for a couple of days now using the `AI Platform > Notebook instances > Open Jupyterlab`. I used the `+ New Instance` option and launched a `Tensorflow` machine but when I click on the `Open Jupyterlab` button, it only gives me

```
504. That’s an error.

That’s all we know.
```

I have tried downgrading the notebook version and restarting service as suggested here.

```
sudo pip3 install notebook==5.7.5
sudo service jupyter restart
```

This brings me to the familiar Jupyterlab screen but then does not persist (I mean when I log back in to the instance, Jupyterlab still throws up the same error).

Is this a bug in Jupyterlab? Any solution?

Comment: I just ran into this problem but root cause probably not the same. This happened when I left my notebook running a long running cell, I suspect something has crashed out of memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than use the Notebook instance interface, a better way to use the awesome Jupyterlab is to directly open up the Firewall on TCP 8888 (or any of your choice) and set the IP address of the instance to static. Essentially, there are two steps:

1. Make the instance accessible through a static IP
2. Make the Jupyterlab app in the VM to re-route to the IP

The detailed procedure is [here](https://hackernoon.com/launch-a-gpu-backed-google-compute-engine-instance-and-setup-tensorflow-keras-and-jupyter-902369ed5272)